# nginx - manipulate request_uri while redirecting

Tags: nginx

I would like to know how to manipulate request_uri in my nginx config.

I am trying to redirect all traffics with uri `domain1.com/post/{slug}` to `domain2.com/blog/{slug}`.

Currently, I set up the following:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name domain1.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain2.com/blog$request_url;
}
```

But the problem is `domain1.com/post/{slug}` is redirected to `domain2.com/blog/post/{slug}`, rather than `domain2.com/blog/{slug}`.

How can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `rewrite ... permanent` statement rather than the `return` statement.

```
rewrite ^/post(.*)$ $scheme://domain2.com/blog$1 permanent;
return 404;
```

Replace the `return 404` with whatever the default case should be for URIs which do not begin with `/post`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.